# There+to be+verb? Is it correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

'' There was made a research'' or' 'there was a research made''? Which one is correct? Can I use '' there+to be+verb'' construction?

Added from OP's comment:

I think both as it depends on what is emphasized. The first sentence focuses on the process of making a research and the second one on the fact that some kind of research exists. Am I right?

Comment: Which do you think is correct and why?

Comment: I think both as it depends on what is emphasized.  The first sentence focuses on the process of making a reaserch and the second one on the fact that some kind of reaserch exists. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Neither of your examples is grammatical or idiomatic.

We don't talk about **a research** in English. We either refer to **research** in general or **the research** when talking about something specific.

> Further research may help to clarify the issue.
>   The research into the faulty gene was done by scientists at X university.

And it's NOT idiomatic to refer to **making research**.

We **do** (or **carry out) research** (using the word as a noun) or **we research** (using it as a verb).

You can use various constructions, such as:

> There is research ....
>   There has been research....
>   There was research....
>   Research that has been done....
>   Research that was done.....

and so on, with other tenses (has been, will be, should be etc).

Note that the word is spelled **research** and NOT reaserch as you have spelled it.